# Effect of using new() in Class destructor in C#

Tags: c#

As an academic exercise, trying to determine what causes the program to exit - It's not a StackOverFlowException but a regular termination. All I am doing is creating a new instance on the class's destructor/finalizer. I was expecting this code to run for ever like a `while(true)` loop..

```
class Animal
{
    static int i = 0;
    public Animal()
    {
        Animal.i = Animal.i + 1;
        Console.WriteLine(i + " Object created.." );
    }

    ~Animal()
    {
        new Animal();
    }

}
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Animal a = new Animal();
    }

}
```

Run 1 Output:

```
76727 Object created..
76728 Object created..
76729 Object created..
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Run 2 Output

```
76818 Object created..
76819 Object created..
76820 Object created..
76821 Object created..
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The garbage collector controls when a finalizer is called, and there is no guarantee that a finalizer will be called at all. It's possible for a program to terminate with objects whose finalizers haven't been called. Most likely in your case, the program reaches a point where it is going to terminate no matter what is left in the GC, and ceases to call any finalizers.

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/finalizers):

> Note
>
> Whether or not finalizers are run as part of application termination is specific to each implementation of .NET. When an application terminates, .NET Framework makes every reasonable effort to call finalizers for objects that haven't yet been garbage collected, unless such cleanup has been suppressed (by a call to the library method `GC.SuppressFinalize`, for example). .NET 5 (including .NET Core) and later versions don't call finalizers as part of application termination. For more information, see GitHub issue dotnet/csharpstandard #291.
>
> If you need to perform cleanup reliably when an application exits, register a handler for the `System.AppDomain.ProcessExit` event. That handler would ensure `IDisposable.Dispose()` (or, `IAsyncDisposable.DisposeAsync()`) has been called for all objects that require cleanup before application exit. Because you can't call Finalize directly, and you can't guarantee the garbage collector calls all finalizers before exit, you must use `Dispose` or `DisposeAsync` to ensure resources are freed.